# Jackson: Deserialize date String `2022-05-18Z` error

Tags: jackson, jackson-modules

When I try to deserialize date from this string format `2022-05-18Z` in Jackson it throws this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2022-05-18Z": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2022-05-18Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

All attempts to configure Date field from this string was unsuccessful, I did:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;
```

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddZ")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime date;
```

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddZ")
    private Date date;
```

What is the right way to deserialize this string yyyy-MM-ddZ format to Date? I believe this "Z" at the end is the timezone, is there a way to represent it in this mask?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. After few more attempts, finally got the solution:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date  date;
```